# Using Sql to find locations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range

I have a table with multiple rows that detail the times that specific locations are open on different days. Given a specific datetime, how can I write a function to find out the name and address of location that is open at such time?

Note:  There is no overlap between the times in the rows so there can only be one location for any given time.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_biz_locations](
    [placeid] [int] 
    [placename] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [place_street] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [place_city] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [sunfrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [sunto] [time](7) NULL,
    [monfrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [monto] [time](7) NULL,
    [tuefrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [tueto] [time](7) NULL,
    [wedfrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [wedto] [time](7) NULL,
    [thufrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [thuto] [time](7) NULL,
    [frifrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [frito] [time](7) NULL,
    [satfrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [satto] [time](7) NULL,


 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_places] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [placeid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Yes. Also I forgot to mention there is no overlap between the times in the rows so there can only be one location for any given time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the day is a monday and you have the date captured in the @date variable

```
if datename(dw,getdate()) = 'Monday' 
begin
 select placename from [dbo].[tbl_biz_locations] and CONVERT(TIME, @date) between monform and monto
end
```

Comment: The question assumes we dont know the day of the week, give a datetime, we need to find out the correct row AND the correct fields to check